# SQL - check unused cte

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, dbt

Let's say I have the below SQL query:

```
with unused_cte as 
   (select 1 as one),
used_cte as
   (select 2 as two)
select * from used_cte
```

I want to know your opinion on how I can automate the catching of unused CTE (the CTE  which is not used in the SQL execution, for Example 'unused_cte' in this case) in the form of SQL assertion or [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) checks or any other suggestions.

Comment: Unused CTEs won't be executed. They will make up bulk to the planner, but won't affect execution time or resources. What's the goal you are pursuing?

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: My goal is to find the unused cte's from the SQL by righting some SQL/script or any other way so that I can remove it from the SQL file automatically using dbt platform if possible

Comment: The Query Planer, tries to optimize the query, so it detects unnecessary Part like your CTE. For detecting use a simple texteditor and search for it, the text has to be unique and it takes 5 minutes to check the complete

Answer (score 1):

If using `dbt-core`, you can add [SQLFluff](https://www.sqlfluff.com/) as your linter locally. Then, after setting it up, it will be able to catch the cases where you have a CTE inside a data model that is not being used.

See example below -> I have a model called `stg_testing.sql` that looks like the following:

```sql
with used_cte as (
  select 1 as fake_id
),

unused_cte as (
  select 2 as fake_id
),

final as (
  select fake_id
  from used_cte
)

select * from final
```

Since SQLFluff detects that the second CTE is not used, it will raise the following problem:

`Query defines CTE (unused_cte) but does not use it. sqlfluff(L045) [Ln 5, Col 2]`

Answer (score 0):

It will not be run, as this simple test shows .

the first CTE is a division by zero, which should produce and error.

But as the unused cte isn't executed, the second valid will run.

Postgres

> ```
> with cte_unused as (select 1/0 as val), cte_used as (select 'it works' as val)
> select * from cte_used
> ```

> ```
> | val      |
> | :------- |
> | it works |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3e3bf1270cfb901a610958fe14c14cc4)*

MySQL

> ```
> with cte_unused as (select 1/0 as val), cte_used as (select 'it works' as val)
> select * from cte_used
> ```

> ```
> | val      |
> | :------- |
> | it works |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e3bf1270cfb901a610958fe14c14cc4)*